# Will data fetch functions declared in Server Components, but called in Client Components, lead to client having access to environment variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch, apollo-client

The [Next.js docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#data-fetching) suggest doing data fetching in React Server Components (RSC):

> Although it's possible to fetch data in Client Components, we
> recommend fetching data in Server Components unless you have a
> specific reason for fetching data on the client. Moving data fetching
> to the server leads to better performance and user experience.

Presume we create one RSC to fetch data, which creates an object we can use for data fetching, then use that in a React Client Component (RCC) to fetch data. Example with Apollo in Next.js:

```
// app/page.js <-- React Server Component
const client = new ApolloClient({
 link: createHttpLink({
   uri: `https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}`,
   credentials: "include",
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
   },
 }),
 cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export const fetch = () => {
  const response = client.query('some query'); // Executes a data fetch, via client object
  return response.data;
}

export default const Page = () => { 
 <div>Test</div>
}
```

And:

```
// app/RCC.js <-- React Client Component
'use client'

import { fetch } from './page';

export default const RCC = () => {
  const fetchedResponse = fetch();
  return <div>{fetchedResponse}</div>
}
```

Is the code architecture above breaking with Next.js principle of doing data fetching in React Server Components?

Are the secret environment variables exposed to the browser here?

Comment: That depends on what *'Some code that establishes a link to the remote server, using secret environment variables'* is. Are the env variables used in the query? If so, yes. Obviously the client has them.

Comment: @super I have now added the code that creates the `client` object (ApolloClient instance). The code that creates that client object is only run on the server, I think (because it is in the RSC).

Comment: I'm assuming we're talking about the access token being the sensetive data? The client sends the access token to the server in a header. So clearly it has the access token. Using any kind of hardcoded token is bad. You should have an auth endpoint that the client can talk to and request an access token that it then can use.

Comment: @super thanks. As you are saying, I guess the server, which creates the `client` object, does not open the door for a requesting client, so to say. The client must send the header on each request, if done from a RCC via the useQuery hook. As a side note, simply executing a fetch request in a RCC will not force it to fetch the data client side. I believe Next.js still does the fetch on the server. If dynamic fetching client-side is desired, one must opt-in to "dynamic rendering" of the component.

Comment: Additionally, the `useQuery` hook will force the fetch to be done by the client, because React contexts cannot be consumed on the server (because they rely on React state).

Comment: @super I am only reading environment variables from `env.local` in development. It is not committed to the repo. In production, the environment variables are added build-time by the host (e.g. Vercel or Netlify). As long as data fetching is never done client-side (which it generally shouldn't), that should work, right?